# What should I use to make a threadsafe "list"?

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety, queue

at first I'd like to tell you what's my aim: I'd like to build a threadsafe list. (I can't use a Queue because afaik we should only use a Queue for FIFO) 
This list should be filled In one thread and in the other thread I'd like to work it off. With working off I mean, that I'd like to always analyze all the entries of the list and sort them against a specific Int-value. Then I'd like to do something with the "most important" entry of the list and so on...

Thank you!

Comment: What you have described sounds like not a list, but queue with priority.

Comment: Thank you Yeldar, is something like that avaliable in the Framework? Or do I have to build my own?

Comment: It looks like there is no such data structure in .NET. You can implement it yourself (maybe, with the help of existent Thread-Safe Collections) or find the solution in the Internet. For example, I have found this on Google: https://github.com/dshulepov/ConcurrentPriorityQueue. However, I am not sure if it works or suitable :) If it works - let me know so that I can write it as an answer.

Comment: Yeldar, I implemented something similar to that. I used this one: https://github.com/BlueRaja/High-Speed-Priority-Queue-for-C-Sharp

It is absolutely easy to use and works great. Thank you for your hint! You can write it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel (which you can if you want), and given that you seems to need a thread safe LIFO system, I recommend you to use the [ConcurrentStack Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: But I don't want a LIFO system. I'd like to "push everything in" and then I'd like to sort it how I want.

Comment: @xileb0 Ow. I've misunderstand the question then, sorry